# Header missing from Ubuntu 16.04 gcc-8?

Tags: compiling, gcc

When I try to compile my program using make and include `immintrin.h`, I get an error that `movdirintrin.h` does not exist. I've scoured the internet trying to figure out what is wrong. I'm using `gcc-8`, and the two libraries that are failing to compile are `glm` and `zlib-ng`. I didn't have a problem compiling until the last update of gcc on ubuntu.

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so very well could have made a stupid mistake, but I am honestly entirely lost at this point.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? [*immintrin.h*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=immintrin.h&sort_by=pkg) is available in official repositories. Where did you get `gcc-8` (it is too new for 16.04 LTS)? Only [Debian Sid has *movdirintrin.h*](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=sid&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=movdirintrin.h). Add output of `apt-cache policy gcc-8` to question.

Comment: I have immintirn.h. It tries to include 'movdirintrin.h', and that's what is giving me the issue. I used `sudo apt-get gcc-8` in the terminal to install gcc-8.

Comment: I can't find a bug report, however the [upstream changelog for gcc-8_8-20180425-1_amd64.deb](https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/gcc-8_8-20180425-1_amd64.deb.html) includes the comment *"Install the movdirintrin.h header file"*

Comment: So it is a problem on their end. Thank you. I had no idea where to look for that info.